# as opposed to for a ritual

Tags: prepositions, style

In the following, is it okay or more aesthetic to remove "for"?

> It seems most likely that the meat from this leg was eaten and that it was eaten for nutrition as opposed to **for** a ritual.

Source: https://edition.cnn.com/2023/06/26/world/fossilized-bone-may-reveal-ancient-cannibalism-scn/index.html

Comment: _For a ritual_ parallels _for nutrition_, but I would have said 'rather than for a ritual' to avoid the awkward juxtaposition of two prepositions. However, I expect she was speaking 'off the cuff'.

Answer (score -1):

No, you shouldn't remove it.

The preposition is needed to show that the two opposing options are:

> the leg was eaten...
> ...for nutrition.
> ...for a ritual.

If you remove the second preposition then it could be read as:

> the leg was...
> ... eaten for nutrition.
> ... a ritual.

"*The leg was a ritual*" makes no sense.

Comment: Why couldn't it be understood as "the leg was eaten for A as opposed to B, where A and B are both nominal expressions? There are no issues with parallelism, if we see things this way. The opposition could be seen as between nutrition and a ritual.

Comment: It could be understood that way, but it isn't clear. That's why I answered as I did, and presumably why the professional writer you are quoting, and their editor, made the same choice. And we're explaining rules and principles here, not just proof-reading specific examples. It might not be mistaken this time, but another example might be.

Comment: There's no way it would have been understood the way you describe if "for" was missing.

Comment: @gotube a non-native speaker could omit quite a lot of words and still be understood a lot of the time. The quote in the question is correct, my answer is valid, and you're missing the point. The site doesn't exist to check individual sentences and say if they are right or wrong. If that were the question, I wouldn't have even bothered to answer it. There is an underlying principle here. You've also fuelled this particular OP who very rarely accepts an answer, unless they tell him what he wants to believe. So, well done. If I'd noticed the username I wouldn't have answered, either